# qsort() stopped sorting before array's end

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have a file with integers.

I read those values into an array line by line. I am trying to quick sort each line. The sort seemed successful until array values completely stopped printing.

I referenced: [one website](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/c/qsort__sorting_array_of_strings__integers_and_structs.xml) and [another website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) for guidance because I have a feeling that the issue has to do with me setting `size_t n_len = sizeof((*array)/sizeof(array));` incorrectly.

Below is only the pertain code:

```
int int_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

while ((p = fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp)) != NULL) {

    p += strspn(p, " \t\n");
    if (*p == '#' || *p == '\0') {

        continue;
    }

    for (count = 0; *p != '\0'; ) {
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)*p)) {
            array[count++] = strtol(p, &p, 10);
        } else {

            p += strcspn(p, " \t\n");
        }

        p += strspn(p, " \t\n");
    }

    size_t n_len = sizeof((*array)/sizeof(array));
    qsort(array, n_len, sizeof(int), int_cmp);

    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < n_len; n++)
        printf("sorted array:%d\n ", array[n]);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
sorted array:1
 sorted array:2
 sorted array:3
 sorted array:4

sorted array:14
 sorted array:14
 sorted array:48
 sorted array:62

sorted array:1
 sorted array:3
 sorted array:5
 sorted array:7

sorted array:123
 sorted array:456
 sorted array:789
 sorted array:1234

sorted array:34
 sorted array:34
 sorted array:34
 sorted array:34

sorted array:1

 sorted array:34
 sorted array:34
 sorted array:34

sorted array:1
 sorted array:2
 sorted array:2
 sorted array:2
```

The output should be:

```
sorted array:1
sorted array:2
sorted array:3
sorted array:4
sorted array:4
sorted array:5
sorted array:5
sorted array:5
sorted array:6

sorted array:14
sorted array:14
sorted array:48
sorted array:62

sorted array:1
sorted array:3
sorted array:5
sorted array:7
sorted array:9

sorted array:123
sorted array:456
sorted array:789
sorted array:1234
sorted array:5678

sorted array:34
sorted array:34
sorted array:34
sorted array:34

sorted array:1
sorted array:1
sorted array:1
sorted array:2
sorted array:2
sorted array:2
sorted array:2
sorted array:2
sorted array:3
sorted array:3
sorted array:4
sorted array:4
sorted array:4
sorted array:5
sorted array:5
sorted array:6
sorted array:7
sorted array:7
sorted array:7
```

Comment: `size_t n_len = sizeof((*array)/sizeof(array));` this may not give you the size you are expecting.

Comment: use `count` instead of `n_len`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you! Solved it. If you want to put it as an answer, I will accept it. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to BLUEPIXY replace the "n_len" argument with "count" in the qsort call.

Comment: I did so. Thank you. (:

Answer (score 2):

Your expression for the array length should be `sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)`, not the other way around, plus your parentheses are incorrect in `sizeof((*array)/sizeof(array))`.

Yet in your code, you should not sort the **whole** array, just the initial part where you stored the numbers parsed from the line.  Use this:

```
    qsort(array, count, sizeof(int), int_cmp);
    printf("sorted array:");
    for (int n = 0; n < count; n++) {
        printf(" %d", array[n]);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Also note that your `int_cmp` function is incorrect for large values:

```
int int_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(int*)a - *(int*)b;  // this may overflow
}
```

If you compare `INT_MIN` and `1`, you return `INT_MIN - 1` which invokes undefined behavior and most likely has a positive value which is incorrect.

Use this function instead:

```
int int_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int na = *(int*)a, nb = *(int*)b;
    return (na < nb) - (nb < na);
}
```

Comment: Another user solved the issue by replacing n_len with count. However, thank you for the note about the possible overflow..I will change that.

Comment: I agree that in general the `int_cmp` function is not safe; it'll work on the sample data.  You're right about the `sizeof()` expression being wrong, but the value used should be `count` (the number of integers on the line) and not the maximum size of the array.

Comment: @Justin_Finland: can you please click on the grey check mark below the answer score to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

The qsort() function takes the number of elements in the array as it's second argument.
Just simply change your code a bit and it will work:

```
size_t n_len =sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
qsort(array, n_len, sizeof(int), int_cmp);

  int n;
  for (n=0; n<n_len; n++)
     printf ("sorted array:%d\n ", array[n]);

int int_cmp (const void * a, const void * b){
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

This will produce the desired answer.But I am hoping that you know that the 'array' is of 'int' type.